# CE Cache or Solspace Static Page Caching: One Faster than the Other?

Tags: cache, ce-cache

I've been developing CMS and now EE websites for so long I forget how fast a static website it. Had to save a CMS website as static earlier. Speeds went from approx. 200 to 300ms to 30ms.

My own site I get approx. 150ms speeds with EE caching.

I installed CE Cache and now get approx. 50 to 100ms speeds, so it does help.

My own site as a static site is approx. 30ms.

Speed is extremely important! So important I am wondering whether to ditch EE and go for static. But I am not giving up! Surely there are ways to make a EE site comparable to static.

I then found Solspace's "Static Page Caching". I have not tried this as I have to purchase it and already just purchased CE Cache.

So... I wondered if anyone has any experience with the two, if one is faster than the other?

Comment: CE Cache does static page caching as well, see the docs: http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-cache/user-guide/static

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using. But it's not as fast as real static page. I'm getting 50ms to 100ms with CE Cache static but the static equivalent is 30ms.

Comment: Stash also does static caching for free now: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/ - however busting the caches will require Mustash (or your own custom extension).

Comment: Also, while speed is undoubtedly critical and each layer of the technology stack is important, I don't think you should spend too much time worrying about the difference between 30ms and 100ms on the back end - the 70ms difference will be utterly unnoticeable to most humans and you're better off optimising the front end.

Comment: We offer a service to speed up peoples websites so would like to speed it up as much as we can.

Comment: At the 2013 EECI in Portland, Mark Croxton stated that a significant advantage of stash caching was you avoided "cache stampede."

Answer (score 4):

I have run into this issue before and I was in the same boat. And "Static Page Caching" didn't do it for me, CE Cache did. I learned that I had to make sure I was really caching the site correctly, such as the right areas and embeds. Also I made sure that I wrote my markup in the best way I could to reduce queries.

I hope this helps, I have always found that before I even start to cache any page, I really make sure my markup reduces the amount of queries.